# Process builder on Many:Many relationships

Tags: process-builder

I have an object Project. Projects are projects and they may - or may not be instantiated by Cases.

Cases may contain information for more than one Project.

Projects may require information that is supplied in more than one case.

I created a linking object called Project Case that has 2 IDs and some forumlae.

So - I thought - lets try using Process Builder for this. Someone clicks a button or sets a status on the project and a new case is created. A case gets to a satisfactory point and a new project is created.

The trouble is that i do not seem to be able to hold the ID of the newly created record anywhere.

Am I expecting too much? Is this not an expected use?

Comment: Have you tried doing your logic in a headless flow and then calling that flow from process builder instead of doing it in the process itself?

Comment: no... good idea. (2 tools, 1 job makes me crazy)

Comment: Actually: I don't have access to headless flows. (as I understand them)

Comment: Headless flows are just flows without UI elements. Does your org have access to Flows???